# How to write the django-piston handler to create and return ApiKey?

Tags: django, api, rest, django-piston

I'm currently working on the project that use Android for client and Django for web server. I decided to use piston-django to create REST API authentication and I've follow this instruction:
[What is the right way to write a django-piston client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457876/what-is-the-right-way-to-write-a-django-piston-client/)
and write my own handler (api/handlers.py) to create and return ApiKey like this:

```
class ApiKeyhandler(Basehandler):
    model = ApiKey
    allowed_methods = ('GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE')
    fields = ('user', 'keys')

    def create(self, request):
        attrs = self.flatten_dict(request.POST)

        if self.exists(**attrs):
            return rc.DUPLICATE_ENTRY
        else:
            apikey = ApiKey(user=request.user)
            apikey.save()

            return apikey
```

and in urls.py I use HttpBasicAuthentication for this handler:

```
 auth = HttpBasicAuthentication(realm="Authentication API")
 apikey = Resource(handler=ApiKeyHandler, authentication=auth)
```

but when I test it with http://hurl.it

[This is the response from GET](http://hurl.it/hurls/40f437de087c2b109a709b53a20b8b2d735c1c01/c807f01a3a03623563242ecbf822e530c603f2d5)

[This is the response from POST method](http://hurl.it/hurls/b87435ab82ac5d3c215f102926037a1c7da6a969/0dea84f2841d2e3579b6bebefcf0c6bfa70fb436)

Can anyone tell me how to write the complete code for this question or any suggestion on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody answer this question, I figured it out myself and some help from my friend. I have to edit ApiKeyHandler to

```
class ApiKeyHandler(BaseHandler):
    model = ApiKey
    allowed_methods = ('GET', 'POST')
    fileds = ('user', 'key')

    def read(self, request):
        # Return the API key for request.user
        values_query_set = request.user.keys.values('key')
        api_key = list(values_query_set)[0]['key']
        return HttpResponse(api_key)

    def create(self, request):
        #Create a new API Key.

        # Check if API key already exists
        if request.user.keys.count() > 0:
            values_query_set = request.user.keys.values('key')
            api_key = list(values_query_set)[0]['key']
            return HttpResponse(api_key)
        else:
            # Create API key
            api_key = ApiKey(user=request.user)
            api_key.save()
        return HttpResponse(api_key)
```

According to [django-piston doc](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#!resources) method`read`is called on GET and method`create`is called on POST. Thus, when client want to create new API key; client need to request HTTP POST to create API key for`request.user`if the API key is not already exists.

Finally in models.py I need to edit the ApiKey model to

```
class ApiKey(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='keys', unique=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=KEY_SIZE, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.key = User.objects.make_random_password(length=KEY_SIZE)

        while ApiKey.objects.filter(key__exact=self.key).count():
            self.key = User.objects.make_random_password(length=KEY_SIZE)

        super(ApiKey, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.key
```

[We need to call the "real" save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

```
super(ApiKey, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and APIKeyAuthenticatin is work now.

Last but not least, when authenticating user, client need to request the HTTP request with HEADER ('Authorization', api_key).`api_key` must match with the`request.user`.